# XSLT - Choose between one of 2 Sitecore fields

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I am very new to XSLT and am trying to edit some code that sets up the breadcrumb navigation for a Sitecore site. Right now, it's set to get the value of the Menu Title field and use that for the breadcrumb navigation. However, there are templates that don't have this field, so I would like to have the option to get the value of Page Title's field in these cases.

I can do this sort of thing with C#, but XSLT is completely different. Any suggestions?

Here is the complete XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--=============================================================
    File: BreadCrumb.xslt                                                                                              
    Copyright notice at bottom of file
==============================================================-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sc="http://www.sitecore.net/sc" xmlns:dot="http://www.sitecore.net/dot" exclude-result-prefixes="dot sc">
  <!-- output directives -->
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <!-- parameters -->
  <xsl:param name="lang" select="'en'" />
  <xsl:param name="id" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="sc_item" />
  <xsl:param name="sc_currentitem" />
  <!-- variables -->
  <!-- Uncomment one of the following lines if you need a "home" variable in you code -->
  <!--<xsl:variable name="home" select="sc:item('/sitecore/content/home',.)" />-->
  <!--<xsl:variable name="home" select="/*/item[@key='content']/item[@key='home']" />-->
  <!--<xsl:variable name="home" select="$sc_currentitem/ancestor-or-self::item[@template='site root']" />-->
  <!-- entry point -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$sc_item" mode="main" />
  </xsl:template>
  <!--==============================================================-->
  <!-- main-->

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="main">
    <!--==============================================================-->
    <div class="bread-crumb-box" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top: -25px;">
      <div class="container" style="width:100%">
        <div class="row">
          <small style="font-size:12px; float:left">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::item">
              <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 2 and @template != 'folder' and @template != 'blogtypefolder'">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="position() != last()">
                    <sc:link class="white">
                      <xsl:call-template name="GetNavTitle" />
                    </sc:link>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!--<strong>-->
                    <xsl:call-template name="GetNavTitle" />
                    <!--</strong>-->
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                  &gt;
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <!--This part is what needs to be adjusted, I believe-->
  <xsl:template name="GetNavTitle">
    <xsl:param name="item" select="." />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="sc:fld( 'navtitle', $item )">
        <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld( 'Menu Title', $item )" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="holder" select="$item/@id" />
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="$item/@name" />-->
        <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Menu Title', sc:item($holder,.))" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Refactor to c# ;)

Comment: um. The rest of the Sitecore community abandoned XSLT like 5 years ago. Or more. A suggestion would be to stick with c# and not try to learn XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT needs to be changed to this:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="sc:fld( 'Menu Title', $item ) != '' ">
    <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld( 'Menu Title', $item )" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Page Title', $item )" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```